# Ideas for Android security project

Tags: android, security

I am a student in Computer Science.As a part of final project I need to do a project on the security side of Android like demonstrating attacks or remedies of that.
I searched for different ideas which I can implement on Android within a span of 2-3 months.
Can anyone please suggest some ideas for simple security apps which I can develop within 2-3 months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main concerns with mobile devices (Not just Android) is privacy. This entails not only privacy from peering eyes, but also people packet sniffing. Supposedly one university/organization(I can't remember which) did a test to see if they could grab data from the air and piece it back together to get some sort of information... Do I think you could do this in 2-3 months? Perhaps, but probably not. 
How about something that create a secure point-to-point data connection between two android phones? Through this pipeline, create the ability to successfully send anything from text to files of varying sizes. Have two versions: one encrypted, the other not. Prove the encrypted pipeline is actually secure by showing the ability to acquire the data from the unencrypted line. 
If this is too time consuming, maybe just simply show all the holes in a generic Android system, whether it's a vanilla Android version or a certain company's spin of it. I'm not saying you have to break a phone, but maybe you could show that you can acquire sensitive data!

Comment: Thanks for all your support. I dealt with the attacks that android devices can be vulnerable to as well as the security concerns raised by android apps.

Answer (score 0):

Make an students attendance system in android. using `ZXing library`.

Every student should have assinged a Barcode or QR code to its ID card and every time students reach at the college the student will scan the card which will stores the date and time of student. if a student not come on time, the app should automatically counts the Late comer and if student is absent then it should count the total absent . and Application should also have a SQlite data base connectivity which should  keep record of each student.

All you need is to download the ZXing Library, from [Here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list)

Import it in your project.

A Sqlite Database connectivity.

Hope this help